# Css Nth-Child Selector Not Selecting Expected Elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to select the 7th and 8th elements of each of the following sections to change display to none.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <a href="https://example.com/96" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 1</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/95" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/94" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 3</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/93" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 4</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/92" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 5</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/91" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 6</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/90" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 7</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/89" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 8</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
        <a href="https://example.com/96" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 1</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/95" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/94" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 3</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/93" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 4</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/92" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 5</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/91" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 6</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/90" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 7</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/89" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 8</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously when doing...

```
.imageblock.col-sm-3:nth-child(7) { display: none; }
```

...nothing happens since those elements are not the 7th child of the parent element.

But when I try...

```
a.recirc-rail_unit:nth-child(7) { display: none; }
```

...nothing happens as well. I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

---

EDIT: using the a tag as a class was a typo. My appologies

Comment: you're selecting `.a` as a class, but it's just a tag `a`

Comment: better consider nth-of-type also

Comment: try `a.recirc-rail_unit:nth-child(7) .imageblock.col-sm-3{ display: none; } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8crqu6s2/

```css
.row > a:nth-of-type(7) {
    display: none;
}

.row > a:nth-of-type(8) {
    display: none;
}
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, the links 7 and 8 are hidden : I removed the `.` before the `a` selector (it's an element, not a class) and set the children numbers to 8 and 9 since your `<h1>` counts as a child.

`a:nth-child(8)` selects the `a` that is the 8th child of its parent, so here it's `.row`.

Hope it helps.

```css
a.recirc-rail_unit:nth-child(8), a.recirc-rail_unit:nth-child(9) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <a href="https://example.com/96" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 1</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/95" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/94" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 3</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/93" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 4</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/92" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 5</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/91" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 6</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/90" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 7</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/89" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 8</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">   
        <h1>Title 2</h1>
        <a href="https://example.com/96" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 1</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/95" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 2</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/94" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 3</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/93" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 4</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/92" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 5</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/91" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 6</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/90" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 7</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="https://example.com/89" target="_blank" class="recirc-rail_unit">
            <div class="image-block col-sm-3">
                    <p>Link 8</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```